# HttpResponseException when trying to retrieve xml file using groovy script

Tags: groovy

It always catches the exception and outputs "Unable to read data for $dId:$alias" when I run read():

```
http = new HTTPBuilder('https://somewebsite.com')

def read(http, path, dId, alias, portalFile, outputFileName) {

   try {
     println "Reading : path:$path, file:$portalFile"

         http.get(path: path,
           contentType: TEXT,
           query: [id:dId, instance:alias, format:'xml', file:portalFile]) {resp, reader ->

           println "response status: ${resp.statusLine}"  
         println 'Headers: -----------'  
       resp.headers.each { h ->     
            println " ${h.name} : ${h.value}"  
       }

       new File(outputFileName).withWriter{out -> out << reader}
        }
  } catch (HttpResponseException h) {
    println "Unable to read data for $dId:$alias"
  }
}
```

If I go to the website using my internet browser and click on the xml file that I need, it works. Is there any way I can output the URL that it connects to?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do to see where things are going on wrong is to enable wire debugging for http builder - this will show you the exact requests and responses that are happening. From this you can see what URL is being fetched, with what parameters and headers, and what came back from the server.

Enabling debugging is documented here - http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/index.html#Logging_and_Debugging

E.g. add the following to your `log4j.properties`

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.http.headers=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.http.wire=DEBUG
```

Or, quicker and dirtier, put this right at the top of your groovy script (YMMV)

```
System.setProperty('org.apache.commons.logging.Log', 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog')
System.setProperty('org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http.wire', 'DEBUG')
```